# Adding another parameter to my script

Tags: powershell, size, directory, subdirectory

i am very very new and i tried out a lot but i can't find a way how to add another property or something to my existing script.

i am searching for subfolder sizes and now i want to prevent the script from showing me empty folders by adding something like

`| where-object size -gt 1KB`  OR something similar to it

i tried to put the pipeline behind others and i also tried to use an -and operator but i had no success. That's why i am asking you now :)

Thats my Script so far.

```
$startFolder = "C:\data1"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum )
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} )
foreach ($i in $colItems)


    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ea SilentlyContinue )
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($subFolderItems.Sum -gt 0)
{
    $i.FullName + " -- + {0:N2} MB" -f ($subFolderItems.sum/1MB)
}
```